# Understanding of $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }\dfrac {1} {n+1}=0$

Tags: real-analysis

Proof of Lecturer. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Choose $N>1/\varepsilon$. Such an $N$ exists by the Archimedean property. For $n\geq N$ we have

$\left| \dfrac {1} {n+1}-0\right| =\dfrac {1} {n+1} < \dfrac {1} {N} < \varepsilon$.

My proof. Let $\varepsilon >0$. We need to find $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$ implies

$\left| \dfrac {1} {n+1}-0\right| =\dfrac {1} {n+1} < \varepsilon$.

By the Archimedean propoerty, there is a $N$ in $\mathbb{N}$ such that we have $N>\dfrac {1} {\varepsilon }-1$. Hence, we have $N+1>\dfrac {1} {\varepsilon }
$. For any $n\geq N$, we have $\dfrac {1} {n+1}\leq \dfrac {1} {N+1} < \varepsilon$.
We are done.

My question is: What is difference between proof of lecturer and my proof? So,can you check my proof?

Comment: Your proof is OK. The only difference would be that your $N$ could be a little more accurate that your lecturer's $N$. But who cares about the exact value of $N$ ?

Comment: It's a little misleading to call the OPs proof "more accurate." @NicolasFRANCOIS It is a looser constraint, but both proofs are equally "accurate."

Comment: If I were to guess, the lecturer might have chosen $N$ that way to avoid nitpicking on the case $1 / \epsilon - 1 \lt 0$ since the Archimedean property is usually stated for positive numbers. Otherwise the proofs are equivalent.

Comment: Why let $N > 1/\epsilon$? Wouldn't it be clearer to let $N = 1/\epsilon$? (In your lecturer's proof, but also applies to yours)

Comment: @jacer21 This is by the Archimedean proporty.

Comment: So, how could be $\dfrac {1} {n+1} < \dfrac {1} {N}$ in the lecturer proof?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : I didn't say the OPs **proof** was more accurate, just that his **bound** $N$ could be more close to the better one than the one of his lecturer. And I don't like, as a teacher, to "drop" arbitrary such $N$ without explaining to my students how to find them themselves. So I think the work of the OP is cleaner, in a teaching way. But that's my own humble opinion ;-)

Comment: @Kahler : $n+1>N$ so...